# On-ear stereo headset with a decent quality microphone at a reasonable price

Tags: headset

I would like a decent quality stereo headset which isn't too expensive (<£100) and doesn't cause my ears to over heat.

- There are lots of high quality over-ear options, but I find wearing these for any length of time becomes uncomfortable (e.g. Logitech Pro Gaming Headset).
- There are lots of cheap on-ear options (<£20), but headphone and microphone quality are difficult to assess, and reviews of specific products are difficult to find - people mainly seem interested in reviewing expensive over-ear headphones.
- There are lots of cheap mono headsets, which are optimised for voice/video conferencing, but I don't get on with only having sound in one ear.
- Similarly, in-ear headsets are not an option, I have several but I don't get on with them for voice/video conferencing.
- I don't need a 'professional' quality mic, but I would like it to be good enough that people no longer complain about it.
- I'm happy to consider a single TRRS jack headset, twin TRS jack, USB, or possibly even Bluetooth wireless, but I have a slight preference for TRRS connection and this would work out of the box with more of my devices.

My current workaday headset is a cheap Trust on-ear TRRS headset, with upgraded pads, but the headphones are very quiet and the microphone rattles, which confuses Zoom, Discord and MS Teams chat and is the cause of the complaints I've been getting.

I also have an Anker Soundbud Slim in-ear bluetooth headset, and it's great on the move, but I don't get on with it at my desk.

Comment: My initial thought is just to get some ~£90 on-ears and get an inline mic cable, since those have usually been sufficient for day-to-day use for me; however, I'm not sure if that'll cut it for you. If not, a V-MODA BoomPro or Modmic is an option, but those have their own restrictions. Would something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucicsFlnpWs) be good enough audio quality?